# How to Convert the row unique values in to columns

Tags: python, pandas

I have this dataFrame

```
dd = pd.DataFrame({'a':[1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2],'feature':[10,10,20,20,10,10,20,20],'h':['h_30','h_60','h_30','h_60','h_30','h_60','h_30','h_60'],'count':[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8]})


   a  feature     h  count
0  1       10  h_30      1
1  1       10  h_60      2
2  1       20  h_30      3
3  1       20  h_60      4
4  2       10  h_30      5
5  2       10  h_60      6
6  2       20  h_30      7
7  2       20  h_60      8
```

My expected output is I want to shift my `h` column  unique values into column and use count numbers as values
like this

```
   a  feature  h_30  h_60
0  1       10     1     2
1  1       20     3     4
2  2       10     5     6
3  2       20     7     8
```

I tried this but got an error saying `ValueError: Length of passed values is 8, index implies 2`

```
dd.pivot(index = ['a','feature'],columns ='h',values = 'count' )
```

[image]

Comment: `dd.pivot(index=['a', 'feature'], columns='h', values='count')` worked for me.

Comment: @ Ch3steR why isn't it working for me? I just added a screenshot

Comment: Try re-running cell `109` and then `110`.

Comment: Tried re-running it, still won't work for me

Comment: Which pandas version are you using? `pd.__version__`?

Comment: Below version `1.1.0` index doesn't accept a list mentioned in below answer.

Comment: right I have '0.23.4'  pandas version

Comment: Consider upgrading `pandas` current `PyPi` version is `1.1.3`. To upgrade use `pip upgrade pandas`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`df.pivot`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.pivot.html) does not accept list of columns as index for versions below `1.1.0`

> Changed in version 1.1.0: Also accept list of index names.

Try this:

```py
import pandas as pd

pd.pivot_table(
    dd, index=["a", "feature"], columns="h", values="count"
).reset_index().rename_axis(None, 1)
```

Comment: Edited the code with `black` to make it in accordance with `PEP-8` and added a few details. Feel free to revert changes if not ok.